# Cloudformation S3bucket creation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Here's the cloudformation template I wrote to create a simple S3 bucket, How do I specify the name of the bucket? Is this the right way?

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Simple S3 Bucket",
  "Parameters": {
    "OwnerService": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "CloudOps",
      "Description": "Owner or service name. Used to identify the owner of the vpc stack"
    },
    "ProductCode": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "cloudops",
      "Description": "Lowercase version of the product code (i.e. jem). Used for tagging"
    },
    "StackEnvironment": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "stage",
      "Description": "Lowercase version of the environment name (i.e. stage). Used for tagging"
    }
  },
  "Mappings": {
    "RegionMap": {
      "us-east-1": {
        "ShortRegion": "ue1"
      },
      "us-west-1": {
        "ShortRegion": "uw1"
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "ShortRegion": "uw2"
      },
      "eu-west-1": {
        "ShortRegion": "ew1"
      },
      "ap-southeast-1": {
        "ShortRegion": "as1"
      },
      "ap-northeast-1": {
        "ShortRegion": "an1"
      },
      "ap-northeast-2": {
        "ShortRegion": "an2"
      }
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "JenkinsBuildBucket": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "BucketName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "-",
            [
              {
                "Ref": "ProductCode"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "StackEnvironment"
              },
              "deployment",
              {
                "Fn::FindInMap": [
                  "RegionMap",
                  {
                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                  },
                  "ShortRegion"
                ]
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "AccessControl": "Private"
      },
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete"
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "DeploymentBucket": {
      "Description": "Bucket Containing Chef files",
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "DeploymentBucket"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Syntax looks good. Are you getting any error after running this?

Comment: Check the values that you're passing in as parameters to construct the name of the bucket. The bucket name must be compliant with AWS S3 naming policies as documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend 'cloudquiz' answer, this is what it'd look in yaml format:

```
Resources:
  SomeS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
        Fn::Join: ["-", ["yourbucketname", {'Fn::Sub': '${AWS::Region}'}, {'Fn::Sub': '${Stage}'}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a really simple Cloudformation template that creates an S3 bucket, including defining the bucketname.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: create a single S3 bucket

Resources:
  SampleBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: sample-bucket-0827-cc
```

You can also leave the "Properties: BucketName" lines off if you want AWS to name the bucket for you. Then it will look like $StackName-SampleBucket-$uniqueIdentifier.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has the BucketName already specified:

```
"BucketName": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        "-",
        [
          {
            "Ref": "ProductCode"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "StackEnvironment"
          },
          "deployment",
          {
            "Fn::FindInMap": [
              "RegionMap",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              "ShortRegion"
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
```

The BucketName is a string, and since you are using 'Fn Join', it will be combined of the functions you are joining.
"The intrinsic function Fn::Join appends a set of values into a single value, separated by the specified delimiter. If a delimiter is the empty string, the set of values are concatenated with no delimiter."
Your bucket name if you don't change the defaults is:
cloudops-stage-deplyment-yourAwsRegion

If you change the default parameters, then both cloudops, and stage can be changed, deployment is hard coded, yourAWSRegion will be pulled from where the stack is running, and will be returned in short format via the Mapping.